# Multiple $(document).ready(function() but only the top couple are firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

### Question: How do I make sure that all of my `$(document).ready` pieces run and not just the first couple?

I am trying to use an external .js file to change the value of hidden fields on my form based upon whether or not a box is checked. Right now my .js file looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('[name="c1"]').on('change', function() {
            $('[name="i1"]').val('Wargo');
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('[name="c2"]').on('change', function() {
            $('[name="i2"]').val('Wargo');
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('[name="c3"]').on('change', function() {
            $('[name="i3"]').val('Wargo');
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('[name="c4"]').on('change', function() {
            $('[name="i4"]').val('Daily');
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('[name="c5"]').on('change', function() {
            $('[name="i5"]').val('Daily');
        });
    });
});

.... (one of these for each variable)
```

Inside of my table where the check boxes are I have:

`<input type="checkbox" id="c1"  name="c1" value="17943">
<input type="hidden" name="i1" value="" />
... (one of these for each box)`

What is happening is that the first 3 of these ready calls will work properly and then none of the other values will change when their box is checked. (I'm testing it on Chrome.) The help forums I've found suggest that it's not looking at the ones further down the page because there is some type of error, but since they are all identical functions I'm not sure how to determine what that error might be and correct it.

So -- How do I make sure that all of my `$(document).ready` pieces run and not just the first couple?

So far I've seen a few suggestions to use `$(document).live` instead of `$(document).ready`, however making that change doesn't affect the end result any. I've also tried combining all of my name change bits of code into one set like I saw on a few pages, but that failed to do anything at all so I went back to separated functions.

I'm using WordPress and the only way to get the .js code onto the page is to have the file loaded from an external file, so moving the code around on the page isn't really an option beyond a very broad header or footer option (at least not without better directions than I've been able to find on Google). Right now the .js file is being called from the header.php file on WordPress.

Comment: `$(function() {});` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function() {});` so you actually have a document ready inside a document ready.

Comment: What Jason said. Also, why do you have a separate `document.ready` for every three lines of code?!?

Comment: Also you can use partial matches in your selectors like this: `$('[name=^"c"]').on('change', function() {});` called a [Starts With selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: The extra/nested `ready()` calls are harmless, though not helpful. Also, please ignore any further advice from anyone suggesting you use the (deprecated, obsolete) `.live()` function. Are you seeing any errors in the   [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Comment: I think you would really benefit from reading the jQuery tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: Consider using either broader selector (like Jason suggests) or some kind of loop, like `$.each(['Wargo', 'Wargo', 'Wargo', 'Daily', 'Daily'], function(i, s){ $('[name="c' + (i+1) + '"]').on('change', function() {
        $('[name="i' + (i+1) + '"]').val('Daily');
    }); })` (that looks ugly in comment, sorry).

Comment: As stated originally, when I tried to put all of the functions under one document ready function it failed to do anything at all. That's why they are all separate. 

Even copying the code below where they are combined together I still get the same result, which is that the first 3 times it will work and after that nothing happens.

I'm happy to go and combine them into one function, but it doesn't fix my underlying problem.

Comment: Actually your code seems to work just fine (http://jsfiddle.net/mmqdthh1/), though very verbose, your error must be elsewhere.

Comment: If it fails altogether when you have them as a single function this would point me in the direction of an error being thrown somewhere. Did you check the console for JavaScript errors?

Comment: If I had to guess it would be with your html.

Comment: Frax, I'm not sure what that's supposed to look like as code, but my first thought is that it's going to be very difficult to count across your .each line and make sure that the value in that line matches up with the value I need it to be. I have over 30 of these variables and these values will have to be changed at least every 3 months, so I need something that is easy to read.

Comment: timothy, sorry, I should have been more clear, it doesn't fail altogether, it does the exact same thing... the first 3 fire and the others don't

Comment: @Amanda OK no problems, it sounds like your HTML is the issue then. Can you please post the full HTML or at least the part which contains all the input fields you're selecting?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're using multiple `document.ready` calls for a reason but if possible, you should combine these into one:

```
$(function() {
    $('[name="c1"]').on('change', function() {
        $('[name="i1"]').val('Wargo');
    });
    $('[name="c2"]').on('change', function() {
        $('[name="i2"]').val('Wargo');
    });
    $('[name="c3"]').on('change', function() {
        $('[name="i3"]').val('Wargo');
    });
    $('[name="c4"]').on('change', function() {
        $('[name="i4"]').val('Daily');
    });
    $('[name="c5"]').on('change', function() {
        $('[name="i5"]').val('Daily');
    });
});
```

Multiple `document.ready` functions are permitted and should work in theory. It sounds like an error may be getting thrown which is preventing the others from being executed. Having them combined in a single function will give you an all or nothing result.

Comment: True, but why would the code in the question not work in the first place?

Comment: This does not fix my underlying problem that only the top 3 are actually occurring.

Comment: I agree, multiple calls should still work (updated answer to extend on this). Having cleaner code to begin with should help the debugging process with less areas for potential problems.

Comment: @Amanda all functions should get executed, if one or more aren't then it leads me to believe an exception is being thrown. Have you checked the console output?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following structure. Put all our events in one document ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('[name="c1"]').on('change', function() {
        $('[name="i1"]').val('Wargo');
    });

 $('[name="c2"]').on('change', function() {
        $('[name="i2"]').val('Wargo');
    });

});
```

Comment: This does not fix my underlying problem that only the top 3 are actually occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a single document ready:

```
$(function() {
    $('[name="c1"]').on('change', function() {
        $('[name="i1"]').val('Wargo');
    });
    $('[name="c2"]').on('change', function() {
        $('[name="i2"]').val('Wargo');
    });
    $('[name="c3"]').on('change', function() {
        $('[name="i3"]').val('Wargo');
    });
    $('[name="c4"]').on('change', function() {
        $('[name="i4"]').val('Daily');
    });
    $('[name="c5"]').on('change', function() {
        $('[name="i5"]').val('Daily');
    });
});
```

Comment: This does not fix my underlying problem that only the top 3 are actually occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like Jason and Timothy were right. When I went digging at the HTML bit it started working. It looks like when I copied and pasted to move things around I hadn't quite fully erased a line of code and it was causing the error. That was probably why when I combined into one function before it still failed, I cleaned it up again and this time and without that extra bit of code hanging out it works fine.

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Better put all the code in a single document ready. Else you can try like

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('[name="c1"]').on('change', function() {
            $('[name="i1"]').val('Wargo');
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function(f) {
        $('[name="c2"]').on('change', function() {
            $('[name="i2"]').val('Wargo');
        });
    });
```